# What is the difference between rvalue and xvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am trying to better understand the `std::move()`. I used to think it creates a cast to an `rvalue` reference. But in the documentation I have come across this:

> `std::move` produces an `xvalue` expression that identifies its argument. It is exactly equivalent to a `static_cast` to an `rvalue` reference type.

It is unclear for me, why there exist `xvalue`'s alongside with `rvalue`'s? Is it a matter of the `C++11` vs. `C++14` standard?

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues?rq=1)

Comment: 1) An xvalue *is* an rvalue. Rvalue is a more general concept. 2) You cannot "cast to a reference", since a cast is an expression, and the type of an expression is always an object type (or void), never a reference. You can, however, cast to lvalue, xvalue or prvalue (by specifying an appropriate type in the cast).

Comment: Simple example: for respectively `T f();`, `T& f()` and `T&& f();`, `decltype(f())` is `T`, `T&` and `T&&`. In other words, these are examples of functions returning, respectively, prvalues, lvalues and xvalues, and the result of the call expression `f()` is a value of the respective category (and of type `T`).